# Passing variable from .feature file as an array argument

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

I am trying to pass the parameters from a .feature file (cucumber) to a method call in a .rb file
heres what i have:
feature file

```
 When I set something to blah
```

step definition for the above feature file:

```
 When /^I set something to (.+)$/ do |value|
 methodcall(["#{value}"]))
 end
```

method in a separate .rb file

```
    def methodcall (a=[],b=[],c=[])
    a.each {|x| 
     do something with x
     }
        b.each {|y| 
     do something with y
     }
        c.each {|z| 
     do something with z
     }
     ...
    end
```

It works fine when I give only one parameter in .feature file . I am hoping that it'll work for one value for each of the array (not tried this though)

but what I want to do is write in feature file something like this

```
       And I set something to "blah,blah1,blah2" and somethingelse to "blah4,blah5" and otherthings to "blah6, blah7"
```

for the above, step definition would look like

```
          When /^I set something to (.+) and somethingelse to (.+) and            
          and otherthings to (.+)$/ do |value, value1, value2|
          methodcall(["#{value}"], ["#{value1}"], ["#{value2}"]))
          end
```

and through the above step definition, have the values in value, value1, value2 to be passed in arguments corresponding to a=[], b=[], c=[] and call the  methodcall() method. can someone please help.. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code

```
methodcall(["#{value}"])
```

You are taking the string value and turning it into the first element of an array, which is then passed to the methodcall().

I believe what you actually want to do is

```
methodcall(value.split(','))
```

This will take your value, break it up by commas and puts each of those as an element of the array.

To illustrate with your example, given that methodcall() is:

```
def methodcall (a=[],b=[],c=[])
    a.each {|x| puts x }
    b.each {|y| puts y }
    c.each {|z| puts z }
end
```

Then

```
value = "blah,blah1,blah2"
methodcall(["#{value}"])
#=> blah,blah1,blah2
```

Where as

```
value = "blah,blah1,blah2"
methodcall(value.split(,))
#=> blah
#=> blah1
#=> blah2
```

Comment: I tried with your approach and I am sure I am doing something silly that is preventing it from running successfully but here is what I did..this is the actual so values might be different.. 
 `target([value.split(',')])`    and I am getting this error `And I set geo targeting to United States,Canada   # step_definitions/adserving_create_steps.rb:90
   expected String or Regexp, got ["United States", "Canada"]:Array (TypeError)`   but when I individually call it like this `target(["United states"])`   it works fine.

Comment: It should be without the square brackets - target(value.split(',')). Having the square brackets is putting the desired array within another array.